# Are there any issues with always preparing SQL statements with PHP?

Tags: php, database, pdo, db2, prepared-statement

Is there any issue with always preparing SQL statements with PHP instead of executing them directly?

Not sure if database system matters, but it's DB2 on System i.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might take a slight performance hit, if they are real prepared statements and not just emulated in the driver. This is because you will have to make two calls to the database, rather than just one.